# Xcode can not be installed on OSX 10.9.2

Tags: ruby, xcode, macos, github, installation

Using OS X 10.9.2 Mavericks

I have troubles installing the github-pages gem. I need to install Xcode first, but that results in an error.
I tried to install Xcode using the command: `xcode-select --install`. The dialog box displays three options: Download Xcode, Not now, Install
When I select 'Install' and after select accept, the process begins and stops after a while. Displaying that the software is not available on the update server.
When I select 'Download Xcode', the App store launches and I can install Xcode.
Still it seems Xcode is not installed, see the following steps.

After I installed Xcode I start Terminal and follow the instructions on [Using Jekyll with pages.](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/)

When I run `sudo bundle install --verbose` in my root folder the compiler generates an `error:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:430:in 'try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)`

You have to install development tools first.

```
Below the output of the `sudo bundle install` command:

Fetching from: https://rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies
HTTP Redirection
Fetching from: https://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies
HTTP Success
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Query List: ["RedCloth", "blankslate", "fast-stemmer", "classifier", "colorator", "highline", "commander", "ffi", "liquid", "rb-fsevent", "rb-inotify", "rb-kqueue", "listen", "maruku", "posix-spawn", "yajl-ruby", "pygments.rb", "redcarpet", "safe_yaml", "parslet", "toml", "jekyll", "kramdown", "rdiscount", "github-pages"]
Query Gemcutter Dependency Endpoint API: RedCloth,blankslate,fast-stemmer,classifier,colorator,highline,commander,ffi,liquid,rb-fsevent,rb-inotify,rb-kqueue,listen,maruku,posix-spawn,yajl-ruby,pygments.rb,redcarpet,safe_yaml,parslet,toml,jekyll,kramdown,rdiscount,github-pages
Fetching from: https://rubygems.org/api/v1/dep...ramdown,rdiscount,github-pages
HTTP Redirection
Fetching from: https://bundler.rubygems.org/ap...ramdown,rdiscount,github-pages
HTTP Success
Query List: ["stemmer", "rake", "bones", "jekyll-redirect-from", "jekyll-mentions", "jemoji", "termios", "jekyll-coffeescript", "sass", "mercenary", "directory_watcher", "open4", "hoe", "albino", "celluloid-io", "celluloid", "rb-fchange", "syntax", "rubypython", "echoe", "psych"]
Query Gemcutter Dependency Endpoint API: stemmer,rake,bones,jekyll-redirect-from,jekyll-mentions,jemoji,termios,jekyll-coffeescript,sass,mercenary,directory_watcher,open4,hoe,albino,celluloid-io,celluloid,rb-fchange,syntax,rubypython,echoe,psych
Fetching from: https://rubygems.org/api/v1/dep...,syntax,rubypython,echoe,psych
HTTP Redirection
Fetching from: https://bundler.rubygems.org/ap...,syntax,rubypython,echoe,psych
HTTP Success
Query List: ["loquacious", "little-plugger", "rdoc", "rspec", "bones-git", "bones-extras", "timers", "facter", "nio4r", "allison", "rubyforge", "gemcutter", "rcov", "RubyInline", "coffee-script", "html-pipeline", "gemoji", "win32-api"]
Query Gemcutter Dependency Endpoint API: loquacious,little-plugger,rdoc,rspec,bones-git,bones-extras,timers,facter,nio4r,allison,rubyforge,gemcutter,rcov,RubyInline,coffee-script,html-pipeline,gemoji,win32-api
Fetching from: https://rubygems.org/api/v1/dep...html-pipeline,gemoji,win32-api
HTTP Redirection
Fetching from: https://bundler.rubygems.org/ap...html-pipeline,gemoji,win32-api
HTTP Success
Query List: ["bones-rcov", "bones-rubyforge", "bones-rspec", "bones-zentest", "git", "coffee-script-source", "execjs", "win32console", "windows-pr", "windows-api", "win32-dir", "sys-admin", "CFPropertyList", "json", "json_pure", "net-scp", "activesupport", "nokogiri", "escape_utils", "rinku", "sanitize", "github-markdown", "github-linguist", "minitest", "rspec-mocks", "rspec-expectations", "rspec-core", "cucumber", "diff-lcs", "spicycode-rcov", "ZenTest", "hitimes", "test-unit"]
Query Gemcutter Dependency Endpoint API: bones-rcov,bones-rubyforge,bones-rspec,bones-zentest,git,coffee-script-source,execjs,win32console,windows-pr,windows-api,win32-dir,sys-admin,CFPropertyList,json,json_pure,net-scp,activesupport,nokogiri,escape_utils,rinku,sanitize,github-markdown,github-linguist,minitest,rspec-mocks,rspec-expectations,rspec-core,cucumber,diff-lcs,spicycode-rcov,ZenTest,hitimes,test-unit
Fetching from: https://rubygems.org/api/v1/dep...rcov,ZenTest,hitimes,test-unit
HTTP Redirection
Fetching from: https://bundler.rubygems.org/ap...rcov,ZenTest,hitimes,test-unit
HTTP Success
Query List: ["thread_safe", "tzinfo", "multi_json", "i18n", "builder", "memcache-client", "libxml-ruby", "multi_test", "gherkin", "term-ansicolor", "treetop", "polyglot", "mime-types", "charlock_holmes", "configuration", "mkrf", "rake-compiler", "spruz", "net-ssh", "mini_portile", "racc", "tenderlove-frex", "rexical", "weakling", "rspec-support", "hpricot", "htmlentities", "win32-security"]
Query Gemcutter Dependency Endpoint API: thread_safe,tzinfo,multi_json,i18n,builder,memcache-client,libxml-ruby,multi_test,gherkin,term-ansicolor,treetop,polyglot,mime-types,charlock_holmes,configuration,mkrf,rake-compiler,spruz,net-ssh,mini_portile,racc,tenderlove-frex,rexical,weakling,rspec-support,hpricot,htmlentities,win32-security
Fetching from: https://rubygems.org/api/v1/dep...ot,htmlentities,win32-security
HTTP Redirection
Fetching from: https://bundler.rubygems.org/ap...ot,htmlentities,win32-security
HTTP Success
Query List: ["trollop", "archive-tar-minitar", "needle", "jruby-pageant", "tins", "atomic", "facets"]
Query Gemcutter Dependency Endpoint API: trollop,archive-tar-minitar,needle,jruby-pageant,tins,atomic,facets
Fetching from: https://rubygems.org/api/v1/dep...uby-pageant,tins,atomic,facets
HTTP Redirection
Fetching from: https://bundler.rubygems.org/ap...uby-pageant,tins,atomic,facets
HTTP Success
Query List: []
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Query List: ["tenderlove-frex", "spicycode-rcov"]
Query Gemcutter Dependency Endpoint API: tenderlove-frex,spicycode-rcov
Fetching from: https://rubygems.org/api/v1/dep...tenderlove-frex,spicycode-rcov
HTTP Redirection
Fetching from: https://bundler.rubygems.org/ap...tenderlove-frex,spicycode-rcov
HTTP Success
Query List: []

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-cflags=-w
checking for main() in -lc... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers. Check the mkmf.log file for more details. You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
--with-redcloth_scan-dir
--without-redcloth_scan-dir
--with-redcloth_scan-include
--without-redcloth_scan-include=${redcloth_scan-dir}/include
--with-redcloth_scan-lib
--without-redcloth_scan-lib=${redcloth_scan-dir}/
--with-clib
--without-clib
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:430:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:509:in `block in try_link0'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tmpdir.rb:88:in `mktmpdir'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:506:in `try_link0'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:530:in `try_link'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:716:in `try_func'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:946:in `block in have_library'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:891:in `block in checking_for'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:336:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:306:in `open'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:336:in `block in postpone'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:306:in `open'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:332:in `postpone'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:890:in `checking_for'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:941:in `have_library'
from extconf.rb:5:in `<main>'

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/RedCloth-4.2.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/RedCloth-4.2.9/ext/redcloth_scan/gem_make.out
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:60:in `run'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:37:in `block in build'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tempfile.rb:324:in `open'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:18:in `build'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/installer.rb:678:in `block (2 levels) in build_extensions'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/installer.rb:677:in `chdir'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/installer.rb:677:in `block in build_extensions'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/installer.rb:652:in `each'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/installer.rb:652:in `build_extensions'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/installer.rb:218:in `install'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:100:in `block in install'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:118:in `preserve_paths'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:93:in `install'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:111:in `block in install_gem_from_spec'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:150:in `with_build_args'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:110:in `install_gem_from_spec'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:265:in `block in install_sequentially'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/forwardable.rb:171:in `each'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/forwardable.rb:171:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:264:in `install_sequentially'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:97:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:15:in `install'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:255:in `install'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:121:in `invoke_command'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:363:in `dispatch'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10:in `start'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:5:in `with_friendly_errors'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/bin/bundle:20:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
An error occurred while installing RedCloth (4.2.9), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install RedCloth -v '4.2.9'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 3):

The issues you are facing are specific to **OSX Mavericks** and the latest version(s) of XCode *(as of today, May/21/2014)*. I'm also on 10.9.2, and I faced the following issues, which are what you're facing too, I believe.

Here are the issues I faced while trying to install/build **Ruby gems** that involve compiling native code and/or some dependencies that do:

- You get something like `Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.` somewhere in your output.

  **Reason:** the ubiquitus **Command Line Tools** are not installed on your system.

  **Solution:** There are 3 ways to install the **Command Line Tools**: **1)** installing the full XCode suite, starting it, and letting it install the **Command Line Tools** for you, **2)** running `xcode-select --install`, which will pop up a dialog asking you if you want to *install the full XCode*, *install only the Command Line Tools*, or *Cancel*. This second approach is what I did and it worked for me once, but I've seen it fail on other machines, since apparently the location where it looks for the package online is sometimes accessible, sometimes not, so try this if you want, but it may not work, and, finally **3)** downloading it from the web at the [**Apple Developer Tools**](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) page *(login with Apple account required)*
- You get something like `clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]` somewhere in your output.

  **Reason:** Recent versions of **XCode** removed support for unused command line arguments, as the [XCode 5.1 release notes mention](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction/Introduction.html):

  > Compiler
  >
  > As of Apple LLVM compiler version 5.1 (clang-502) and later, the optimization level -O4 no longer implies link time optimization (LTO). In order to build with LTO explicitly use the -flto option in addition to the optimization level flag. (15633276)
  >
  > The Apple LLVM compiler in Xcode 5.1 treats unrecognized command-line options as errors. This issue has been seen when building both Python native extensions and Ruby Gems, where some invalid compiler options are currently specified.
  >
  > Projects using invalid compiler options will need to be changed to remove those options. To help ease that transition, the compiler will temporarily accept an option to downgrade the error to a warning:
  >
  > -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future
  >
  > Note: This option will not be supported in the future.
  >
  > To workaround this issue, set the ARCHFLAGS environment variable to downgrade the error to a warning. For example, you can install a Python native extension with:
  >
  > $ ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future easy_install ExtensionName
  >
  > Similarly, you can install a Ruby Gem with:
  >
  > $ ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future gem install GemName (16214764)

  **Solution:** the solution is mentioned on the snippet from the XCode release notes above, and basically implies setting environment variable `ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future` before running the `gem` install, like this:

  ```
  export ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future
  gem install <your-desired-gem>
  ```

  ... or, if you need to execute it as `sudo`, put the above 2 lines in a script and execute it as `sudo`, or run it as `sudo` inline like this:

  ```
  sudo bash -c "export ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future; gem install <your-desired-gem>;";
  ```

  **Note:** the solution above (setting the `ARCHFLAGS` environment variable) is going to stop working at some point in the future, as indicated in the aforementioned release notes. Hopefully, by that time current **Ruby gems** will have removed unused command line options from their `Makefile`s.

**NB:** I used the approach outlined above to successfully install the `github-pages` **Ruby gem** in **OSX** 10.9.2

Answer (score 1):

Once you install from the App Store, find Xcode in your Applications directory and launch it (not from the terminal). It will likely tell you it needs to download a few more things. Let it. You can then go ahead and follow instructions for other software that requires Xcode. If it still doesn't work, it is likely a problem with the installation instructions of the other software. I would contact the maintainer of that software to ask about specifics. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks nsdebug for your quick answer. After starting Xcode from the Applications directory it installed components. However, the problem is still there. After selecting sudo bundle install it runs, ending with the following:
An error occurred while installing RedCloth (4.2.9), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install RedCloth -v '4.2.9'` succeeds before bundling.
Do you or others have any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with RedCloth - try installing another (simpler?) gem to see that it works in general. Then you'll know where to look next - is it a ruby issue or a RedCloth issue.

Comment: Thanks nsdebug! I will recontact the Github helpdesk for this

Comment: The helpdesk suggested to use the following command: sudo gem install sqlite3 --verbose

This results in the following output I sent to the helpdesk. They conclude: I suspect this is also a problem with the Xcode command line tools not being installed properly. 

Output:
clang: error: unknown argument: '-multiply_definedsuppress' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [sqlite3_native.bundle] Error 1
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.